# Accepting and Sending Cookies with Mechanize

Tags: python, cookies, mechanize, shibboleth

I need to fill in a login form on a webpage that requires cookies and get some information about the resultant page. Since this needs to be done at very weird hours at night, I'd like to automate the process and am therefore using mechanize (any other suggestions are welcome - note that I have to run my script on a school server, on which I cannot install new software. Mechanize is pure python so I am able to get around this problem).

The problem is that the page that hosts the login form requires that I be able to accept and send cookies. Ideally, I'd like to be able to accept and send all cookies that I the server sends me, rather than hard-code my own cookies.

So, I set out to write my script with mechanize, but I seem to be handling cookies wrong. Since I can't find helpful documentation anywhere (please point it out if I'm blind), I am asking here.

Here is my mechanize script:

```
import mechanize as mech

br = mech.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
print "No Robots"
br.set_handle_redirect(True)
br.open("some internal uOttawa website")
br.select_form(nr=0)
br.form['j_username'] = 'my username'
print "Login: ************"
br.form['j_password'] = 'my password'
print "Password: ************"
response = br.submit()
print response.read()
```

This prints the following

```
No Robots
Login: ************
Password: ************

<html>
<body>
    <img src="/idp/images/uottawa-logo-dark.png" />
    <h3>ERROR</h3>
    <p>
        An error occurred while processing your request.  Please contact your helpdesk or
        user ID office for assistance.
    </p>
    <p>
       This service requires cookies.  Please ensure that they are enabled and try your 
       going back to your desired resource and trying to login again.
    </p>
    <p>
       Use of your browser's back button may cause specific errors that can be resolved by
       going back to your desired resource and trying to login again.
    </p>
        <p>
           If you think you were sent here in error,
           please contact technical support
        </p>       
</body>
</html>
```

This is indeed the page that I would get if I disabled cookies on my Chrome browser and attempted the same thing.

I've tried adding a cookie jar as follows, with no luck.

```
br = mech.Browser()
cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)
```

I took a look at multiple mechanize documentation sources. [One of them](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/hints.html#cookies) mention

```
A common mistake is to use mechanize.urlopen(), and the .extract_cookies() and 
.add_cookie_header() methods on a cookie object themselves. 
If you use mechanize.urlopen() (or OpenerDirector.open()), 
the module handles extraction and adding of cookies by itself,
so you should not call .extract_cookies() or .add_cookie_header().
```

This seems to say that my first method should work, but it doesn't.

I'd appreciate any help with this - it's confusing, and there seems to be a severe lack of documentation.

Comment: I'd personally write this using `requests` if possible - does http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/doc.html#supplying-a-cookiejar help? (it seems to imply passing an opener handler is necessary) (edit: and now I've read elsewhere that seems to contradict that... so I'm tending to agree on the docs!)

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: have you got the solution? I am looking for the answer

Comment: @John: sorry, but no. Also, the University changed their website to one that was more script-friendly, so I've given up on this question. Sorry that I wasn't able to help you out. If you'd like the answer, you could put a bounty on this question to entice other users to answer it. I will likely accept the answer that you award the bounty to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came across the exact same message while authenticating a Shibboleth website with Mechanize, just because I made the same mistake than you. And it looks like I figured it out.

### Short answer

The link you need to open is:

```
br.open("https://web30.uottawa.ca/Shibboleth.sso/Login?target=https://web30.uottawa.ca/hr/web/post-register")
```

Instead of:

```
br.open("https://idp.uottawa.ca/idp/login.jsp?actionUrl=%2Fidp%2FAuthn%2FUserPassword")
```

### Why?

> Shibboleth: Connect easily and securely to a variety of services with
>   one simple login.

The Shibboleth login itself is useless if you don't tell him which service you want to login. Let's analyse the HTTP headers and compare the cookies you get for both queries.

**1. Opening** https://idp.uottawa.ca/idp/login.jsp?actionUrl=%2Fidp%2FAuthn%2FUserPassword

```
Cookie: JSESSIONID=C2D4A19B2994BFA287A328F71A281C49; _ga=GA1.2.1233451770.1401374115; arp_scroll_position=-1; tools-resize=tools-resize-small; lang-prev-page=en; __utma=251309913.1233451770.1401374115.1401375882.1401375882.1; __utmb=251309913.14.9.1401376471057; __utmz=251309913.1401375882.1.1.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided); lang=en
```

**2. Opening** https://web30.uottawa.ca/Shibboleth.sso/Login?target=https://web30.uottawa.ca/hr/web/post-register

```
Cookie: JSESSIONID=8D6BEA53823CC1C3045B2CE3B1D61DB0; _idp_authn_lc_key=fc18251e-e5aa-4f77-bb17-5e893d8d3a43; _ga=GA1.2.1233451770.1401374115; arp_scroll_position=-1; tools-resize=tools-resize-small; lang-prev-page=en; __utma=251309913.1233451770.1401374115.1401375882.1401375882.1; __utmb=251309913.16.9.1401378064938; __utmz=251309913.1401375882.1.1.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided); lang=en
```

**What's the difference?** You got one more cookie: `_idp_authn_lc_key=1c21128c-2fd7-45d2-adac-df9db4d0a9ad;`. I suppose it is the cookie saying "I want to login [there](https://web30.uottawa.ca/hr/web/post-register)".

> During the authentication process, the IdP will set a cookie named
>   _idp_authn_lc_key. This cookie contains only information necessary to identify the current authentication process (which usually spans
>   multiple requests/responses) and is deleted after the authentication
>   process completes.
>
> *Source: https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/IdPCookieUsage*

---

**How did I find** [that link](https://web30.uottawa.ca/Shibboleth.sso/Login?target=https://web30.uottawa.ca/hr/web/post-register)? I indeed digged the web and found that https://web30.uottawa.ca/hr/web/en/user/registration redirects to the login form with the following link:

```
<a href="https://web30.uottawa.ca/Shibboleth.sso/Login?target=https://web30.uottawa.ca/hr/web/post-register" 
   class="button standard"><span>Create your account using infoweb</span></a>
```

So that was not a problem with Mechanize, but more that Shibboleth is a little hard to understand at first glance. You will find more information on the Shibboleth authentification flow [here](https://www.switch.ch/aai/demo/2/expert.html).

Answer (score -3):

The website you're submitting your form data to probably needs a CSRF token (a cookie provided in the form you're skipping the download of.)

Try using Requests:

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#cookies

Look for the cookies and/or hidden form fields and then fire away.

Comment: I got the cookies from the page using `r = requests.get(url)` and `r.cookies`. I then set the `cookiejar` of my `mechanize.Browser` as `br.set_cookiejar(r.cookies)`. Still no luck. Thoughts?